# Swift / Populate UITableView with Array.count of elements matching certain condition

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I'm populating my UITableView by:

```
var eventDates: [NSMutableDictionary] = []

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

      return eventDates.count
}
```

Every `eventDate` within `eventDates` has a `valueForKey("monthsYear")`.

Hardcoded I want now `eventDates.count` only return the eventDates with the `valueForKey("monthsYear") == "September 2016"`.

In other words, to explain it one more time:

`eventDates.count` = 10. But only 5 of them match the condition `valueForKey("monthsYear") == "September 2016"`.

How do I get only those 5 elements to populate the `UITableView` (with only 5 rows).

In theory something like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let returnValue = 0
    for date in eventDates where date.valueForKey("monthsYear")  == "September 2016" {
           returnValue++
    }
    return returnValue
}
```

Help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need to do is a simple Filter

```
let sepDates = eventDates.filter() { $0.valueForKey("monthYear") == "September 2016" }
return sepDates.count
```

**some not answer related stuff stuff**

One Advice, try to use models to avoid using valueForKey, so you array would look like

```
var eventDates: [EventDate] = []
```

good luck and have fun ;)

Comment: thanks for the tipp on the models. but how do set them? currently it tells me. Use of undeclared type 'EventDate'. as expected

Comment: I'm getting: `Value of type 'NSMutableDictionary' has no member 'monthYear'` so I guess your answer assumes that i'm using models?

Comment: öhm, you have to create a class or struct that has the values you need as properties, means your current dictionary is you raw data of key value pairs and you need to create the right class/struct for your needs

Comment: well, yes sorry. You can use $0.valueForKey etc.

Comment: $0 means the object in the list of your eventDates. This is currently a NSMutableDictionary

Comment: tried it. works. awesome. thank you very much for your efford as well as the tip. i'll do so and construct structs and use them instead of NSMutableDictionary. thank you

Comment: i updated the answer with valueForKey. But of you have a real model as array entries you could use $0.monthYear. Oh and this will work because valueForKey is not checking if this property exists, so if not it will crash in runtime